# Finding Records Between 2 Times

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to get the records between two dates. Specifically between the start of the day and the time now. This is my query but it doesn't work for me. I have a MYSQL database

```
var query = (SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `EventTime` < NOW() AND `EventTime` >= '" + dtstartofday + "'  AND `PersonSel` = '" + personassigned + "' AND `PersonID` = '" + id + "'");
```

`dtstartofday` is of `DateTime` type.

Comment: Clarify "doesn't work"   Does it return an error?   Return unexpected data?   Return no data?

Comment: You need to use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Query looks good, what is value of dtstartofday ?

Comment: @always_a_learner actually, I think a lot of devs (myself included) would say the query looks like a terrible security risk. http://Bobby-tables.com

Comment: @Bobby question was not intended to asses security concern. many times we manipulate our code prior to put on stackoverflow for sake of simplicity..kindly be stick with question concern

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It’s giving me unexpected results. It’s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using string concatenation to put query values directly into your SQL string. Don't do this, for a variety of reasons, one of which is the problem you're seeing here - how c# chooses to format the date as string, according to your regional preferences, and how MySQL chooses to parse the string as a date will have direct consequences for how the query runs. As a coarse example, if your date goes in as '2/3/2000' meaning third of feb, you could be using a mysql that interprets it as second of March. Alternatively you might find that c# is representing the date as something mysql doesn't recognise as a date so it is instead converting the EventTime date to a string and then comparing the strings, which is very unlikely to work out (and slow, because of all the conversions)

Either adjust your query so the start of day calculation is done by the db, and parameterize the other elements of your query:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `EventTime` < NOW() AND `EventTime` >= CURDATE()  AND `PersonSel` = @personSel AND `PersonID` = @personID"
```

Or parameterize the start date properly rather than passing its value as a string:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `EventTime` < NOW() AND `EventTime` >= @eventTimeFrom  AND `PersonSel` = @personSel AND `PersonID` = @personID"
```

To add values for the parameters you declare its name, type and value:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eventTime", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtstartofday; //dtstartofday is a c# datetime representing midnight today e.g DateTime.Date
cmd.Parameters.Add("@personSel", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = personassigned;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@personID", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = id;

var x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

It is important to appreciate the difference between having the server do the time and your local machine do the time, especially if they are in different zones, but even if their clocks drift just a little. At some moment what each machine thinks of as "today" will differ. Consider it carefully

---

Later, when you're bored of writing this kind of code endlessly, you can install Dapper, an extension that does it for you. Take a look at http://dapper-tutorial.net for examples of how it will reduce code like this to just two lines; query and variables in, usable objects out.

Comment: I will try this out! Thanks for the reply. This is exactly what I needed, someone to explain how to do it correctly. I will post my results

Comment: I have a db query question though. I've been using the Micron ORM to access my database. If I use the following code as an example, would it still be prone to SQL injection?         MicronDbContext micron = new MicronDbContext();

 var customers = micron.GetRecords<Customer>(
                      new Customer()
                      {
                        City = "Nairobi"
                       }
                     );

  foreach (var customer in customers)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerName);
   }

Comment: Typically the only way using an ORM is liable to sql injection is a) if the ORM is faulty or b) you use its "execute raw sql" feature to execute an injection prone sql. Any time that you concatenate a *value* into an sql you create an injection prone sql. If any concatenation is being done, you should always *concatenate a parameter placeholder* into the sql and then add the parameter *value* into the parameters collection. There is never a need to concat *values* directly into sql